# How do I get the orientation from a open3d.geometry.OrientedBoundingBox?

Tags: python, quaternions, open3d

I've created a Oriented Bounding Box from a clustered sub point cloud of a Velodyne Lidar (rotating laser sensor). I want to get the orientation of the Bounding Box (preferable as a quaternion).

```
subpcd_o3d = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.array(subpcd))
o3d_bbox = o3d.geometry.OrientedBoundingBox.create_from_points(subpcd_o3d)
```

The Documentation has no such method: http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.geometry.OrientedBoundingBox.html

This is confusing. Why is there apparently no orientation of the oriented bounding box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the link you shared, I see the OBB object has the following properties: center, extent and R. If you can access them then you can get position and orientation. Center is a point (x,y,z), extent are three lengths in x, y and z direction and R is a rotation matrix. Columns of R are three orthogonal unit-vectors pointing on *rotated* x, y and z directions.

I think you are interested in orientation, so R is the orientation matrix. You can convert it to quaternion using the matrix-to-quaternion method on this page: https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/